# React Boilerplate unable to fix click event

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I am trying to implement one functionality in [React Boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/7f145034e4a3bd91f30fd98fd7c71f8f)

[1](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/7f145034e4a3bd91f30fd98fd7c71f8f): https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate I have downloaded the code and run this command:

```
npm run setup
```

And it generated default homepage and feature page and then I run this command:

```
npm run generate
```

And generated the main container and added a link to the header component. I am trying to dispatch one-click action but it is not working. Have a look at the code I am using: [Link to Action and Reducer](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/7f145034e4a3bd91f30fd98fd7c71f8f)

I have added this code in index.js:

```
<button onSubmit={onChangeUsername}>Click me</button>
```

and dispatching it using:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onChangeUsername: evt => dispatch(changeUsername(evt.target.value)),
  };
```

I don't know why it is not working do I need to add this into the global reducer. This react boilerplate is good but I am unable to solve this puzzle.

Comment: try 

<button onSubmit={()=>onChangeUsername}>Click me</button>

Comment: Not working bro I have tried all things but react boilerplate has many dependencies.

Comment: Does the button click cause a dispatch? put a console.log inside the corresponding reducer to debug.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? It seems to me that `evt.target` would be the button here, which has no value at all.

Comment: It is not dispatching it is doing nothing.

Comment: I think it is "dispatching", but `event.target.value` is an empty string (it is a value of the button element), so you are sending it nothing. Where is your input with user name?

Comment: No it is not working I removed that target

Comment: That is not much helping

Comment: I solve that I used this: <button onClick={onChangeUsername}>Click me</button>    onClick in place of onSubmit